# Hls video player in kivy or KivyMd

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I have made a streaming website and want to make an app for it. The backend of the website is made in Python as I am a Python developer and want to make an app for it but the problem is that I do not know if Kivy or KivyMd has any way to play HLS (HTTP live streaming service) videos. So if anyone knows how to make a video player(for HLS) in Kivy or KivyMd and shares it. It would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that simply using the kivy `VideoPlayer` will work as long as you are using the `ffpyplayer` implementation. Try adding:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_VIDEO'] = 'ffpyplayer'
```

before any kivy imports.